# Bug in Primefaces tabs - not displaying properly tables

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem in Primefaces tabs. For some reason the tabs are not visualized properly. This is part of the source code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
        <style type="text/css">
            .settingsHashMap { font: 80% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> Rack Management Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>
        </div>  
        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Datacenter Profile" style="position:relative" value="resources/images/logo_datacenter_profile.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMapz" class="settingsHashMap" style="width:1150px; height:400px; position:absolute; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form>  
                        <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">  

                            <p:tab id="tba1" title="General">  
                                <h:panelGrid>  

                                    <h:form id="general">
                                        <table>
                                            <ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.dataList}">

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Component ID</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.componentstatsid}" 
                                                                      rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.componentstatsid}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                        
                                                ..............................
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Power Capacity Watt</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.powercapacitywatt}" 
                                                                      rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.powercapacitywatt}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                                                    </td>                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Description</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.description}" 
                                                                      rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.description}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
                                                    </td>                                    
                                                </tr>

                                            </ui:repeat>
                                        </table>

                                    </h:form>           


                                </h:panelGrid>  
                            </p:tab>  

                            <p:tab id="tab2" title="Servers">  
                                <h:panelGrid>  

                                    <h:form id="zones" >
                                        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
                                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                                        <h:dataTable onmouseover="addOnclickToDatatableRows();" id="dataTable" headerClass="columnHeader" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                                            <!-- Check box -->
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox style="margin-left: 0px;" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.mainSelectAll}" class="checkall" >
                                                        <f:ajax listener="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.selectAll}" render="@form" />
                                                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.selectedIds[item.datacenterid]}" >
                                                    <!-- if the user deselects one row deselect the main checkbox -->
                                                    <f:ajax listener="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.deselectMain}" render="@form" />
                                                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                                <!-- Click on table code -->  
                                                <h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" value="ZoneProfile.jsf" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:black">
                                                    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.datacenterid}" />
                                                </h:outputLink>
                                            </h:column>
                                            <!-- Row number -->
                                            ..............................
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:commandLink value="Description" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:black">
                                                        <f:ajax render="@form" />
                                                    </h:commandLink>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{item.description}" />
                                            </h:column>

                                        </h:dataTable>

                                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="first" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageFirst}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow == 0}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="prev" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pagePrevious}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow == 0}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="next" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageNext}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow + DCProfileTabZonesController.rowsPerPage >= DCProfileTabZonesController.totalRows}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;    

                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="last" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageLast}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow + DCProfileTabZonesController.rowsPerPage >= DCProfileTabZonesController.totalRows}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                                        <h:outputText value="Page #{DCProfileTabZonesController.currentPage} / #{DCProfileTabZonesController.totalPages}" />
                                        <br />

                                        <!-- The paging links -->
                                        <ui:repeat value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pages}" var="page">
                                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.page}"
                                                           rendered="#{page != DCProfileTabZonesController.currentPage}" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">
                                                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                                          rendered="#{page == DCProfileTabZonesController.currentPage}" style="text-decoration:none;color:gray;"/>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                        <br />

                                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="Set" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageFirst}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;
                                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                                        <!-- hidden button -->
                                        <h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.deleteSelectedIDs}" style="display:none">
                                            <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>

                                        <!-- the delete button -->
                                        <h:button styleClass="bimage" value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog(this, 'Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />

                                        <!-- New Zone -->
                                        <h:commandButton id="newzone" styleClass="lbimage" value="New Zone" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.navigateToNewZone()}">
                                            <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script> 
                                    </h:form>         



                                </h:panelGrid>  
                            </p:tab>  

                            <p:tab id="tab3" title="HVAC">  
                                <h:panelGrid>  

                                    <h:form id="hvac" >
                                        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
                                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                                        <h:dataTable onmouseover="addOnclickToDatatableRows();" id="dataTable" headerClass="columnHeader" value="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
                                            <!-- Check box -->
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox style="margin-left: 0px;" value="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.mainSelectAll}" class="checkall" >
                                                        <f:ajax listener="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.selectAll}" render="@form" />
                                                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.selectedIds[item.componentstatsid]}" >
                                                    <!-- if the user deselects one row deselect the main checkbox -->
                                                    <f:ajax listener="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.deselectMain}" render="@form" />
                                                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                                                <!-- Click on table code -->  
                                                <h:outputLink id="lnkHiddenh" value="HVACProfile.jsf" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:black">
                                                    <f:param name="id" value="#{item.componentstatsid}" />
                                                </h:outputLink>
                                            </h:column>
                                            <!-- Row number -->
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:outputText value="№" />                                    
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + DCProfileTabHVACController.firstRow + 1}" />
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:commandLink value="HVAC ID" actionListener="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.sort}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:black">
                                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="COMPONENTSTATSID" />
                                                        <f:ajax render="@form" />
                                                    </h:commandLink>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{item.componentstatsid}" />
                                            </h:column>
                                            ............................
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">
                                                    <h:commandLink value="Date Deployed" actionListener="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.sort}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:black">
                                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="DATEDEPLOYED" />
                                                        <f:ajax render="@form" />
                                                    </h:commandLink>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{item.datedeployed}" />
                                            </h:column>

                                        </h:dataTable>

                                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="first" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.pageFirst}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.firstRow == 0}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;


                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="prev" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.pagePrevious}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.firstRow == 0}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="next" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.pageNext}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.firstRow + DCProfileTabHVACController.rowsPerPage >= DCProfileTabHVACController.totalRows}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;    

                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="last" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.pageLast}"
                                                         disabled="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.firstRow + DCProfileTabHVACController.rowsPerPage >= DCProfileTabHVACController.totalRows}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                                        <h:outputText value="Page #{DCProfileTabHVACController.currentPage} / #{DCProfileTabHVACController.totalPages}" />
                                        <br />

                                        <!-- The paging links -->
                                        <ui:repeat value="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.pages}" var="page">
                                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.page}"
                                                           rendered="#{page != DCProfileTabHVACController.currentPage}" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">
                                                <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                                          rendered="#{page == DCProfileTabHVACController.currentPage}" style="text-decoration:none;color:gray;"/>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                        <br />

                                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                                        <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="Set" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.pageFirst}" >
                                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;
                                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                                        <!-- hidden button -->
                                        <h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.deleteSelectedIDs}" style="display:none">
                                            <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>

                                        <!-- the delete button -->
                                        <h:button styleClass="bimage" value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog(this, 'Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />

                                        <!-- New HVAC -->
                                        <h:commandButton id="newhvac" styleClass="lbimage" value="New HVAC" action="#{DCProfileTabHVACController.navigateToNewHVAC()}">
                                            <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>
                                        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script> 
                                    </h:form>     
                                </h:panelGrid>  
                            </p:tab>  

                        </p:tabView>  
                    </h:form>  

                </div>   

            </div>  
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the result that I get:

[image]
[image]

I suppose that I have a problem somewhere into the tabs but I cannot find it. Can you help me please to fix the problem?

P.S in Firebug I get this error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById("form:dataTable") is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your javascript I think you are getting the id of the dataTable using:

```
document.getElementById("form:dataTable")
```

and you do not have any form id="form" or any dataTable with id="dataTable" so it was returning null.

Also you should not be nesting forms like you did for the below form.

```
<h:form id="general">
```